# Promise Issue: Checking for video in cache

Tags: javascript, caching, search, promise, return-value

I'm getting the promise and not the value from my cache searching function. I can't seem to get the function to return an actual value, only a promise.

I've already written out the function that opens the cache and can actually locate the video. I've even got the function able to decipher if the cache.match is an undefined response or an actual video.

```
let inCache = video => {
  return caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
    return cache.match(video).then(response => {
      if(response != undefined) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }).then(result => {
      return result;
    });
  });
}
```

When I console.log this function, I get a promise that is usually still **pending** but it does give me the value, just inside of a **PromiseValue** instead of as output.

Comment: `.then(result => {
      return result;
    })` always makes it look like you're trying to get a value synchronously from asynchronous code ... you're right, inCache will be a promise, because that's what `.then` returns, always

Comment: I'm still quite new at this promise thing. If I wanted to get that value of true or false, what would I need to change?

Comment: change in what you've written? nothing, it's how you **use** `inCache` that needs to change

Comment: oh, your code above is simplified to `let inCache = video => caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.match(video)).then(response => response != undefined);` - but you use `inCache` like `inCache(something).then(result => { here result is true or false})` ... or `result = await inCache(something)` when used inside an `async` function

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but, change how I'm using inCache? So instead of trying to use it as a function, I'd need to pass it to a higher order function or something like that?

Comment: no, you still use it as a function, knowing that function returns a promise, to access the value, use `.then` just like in the code you posted - please show how you are using `inCache` and perhaps you can then be shown how to use it properly

Comment: I see. Well, I was merely testing it with a console.log() to see if the value was returning properly. It sounds though like I was doing things fine and just using it improperly? The best option would be for me to use the .then()s after the function runs so something like `inCache.then(...)` would be a better fit?

Comment: test it like this: `inCache(whatever).then(console.log)`

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much Bravo!

Comment: @moon-meister "I'm still quite new at this promise thing." think: online shopping. "I wanted to get that value of true or false" I know. You just pressed order and want the stuff you've ordered. Not such a puny message *promising* you that the order will be processed ... A Promise is a wrapper for a value that will be available to you eventually. **But not yet.** That's why you can not "unwrap" the  values.

Comment: True. Didn't think of it that way but that definitely helps! I'll credit you for the help in my answer! :)

Comment: Off topic: here a more straight forward version of your function: `const inCache = video => caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.match(video)).then(value => value != undefined);`

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'm still learning so I'll give that a go when I start refactoring it to go with my other code blocks. Appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Actually made the update now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bravo again for helping me understand the issue!

The inCache function is working fine. The way I'm using it was incorrect. Instead of trying to use the function in a console.log function, I was supposed to call the function (because it's async and will always return a promise) from elsewhere and use the .then() after the promised was returned/resolved.

A simple example of what I did to get the actual values is here:

```
let test = setTimeout(() => {
  inCache(<my-video>)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
  clearTimeout(test);
}, 5000);
```

This gave me exactly what I wanted which is a true or false value in the console.